# How to get a list of the <li> elements in an <ul> with Selenium in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver I need to perform and action(click) on the first account item, do something, then come back and repeat the process again on the next item. It can potentially be up-to 90 account items so I'm trying to avoid hard coding all 90. any idea how to perhaps loop through the account-list?

```html
<ul class="account-list">
  <li class="account-item">one item</li>
  <li class="account-item">two items</li>
  <li class="account-item">three items</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't iterate over a list of elements in Selenium because their object references will become invalid when the DOM changes (StaleElement exception), but you can do it by index number so long as the size of your list doesn't change

```
elements = @driver.find_elements(css: ".account-item>a")    
elements.size.times do |i|
  @driver.find_element(css: ".account-list > li:nth-child(#{i})>a").click
  # Do something
  @driver.navigate.back
end
```

Comment: thanks, I do get an error were Selenium can't find the element. I tried a few different ways but still can't get it. Failure/Error: @driver.find_element(:link, ".account-list > li:nth-child(#{i}) > a").click
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError:

Comment: You can try putting in a wait before the click in case it is a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by getting the all elements by their `css` then iterate throutght the elements as following:

```
elems = driver.find_elements(:css => ".account-list > li")
url = driver.current_url

for i in 0..elems.size
 # wait until the element loads
 wait.until { driver.find_element(:css => ".account-list > li:nth-child(#{i})")}

 elems[i].click()
 #do your tests
 # ...

 # go back
 driver.navigate.to url     
end
```

Comment: if the element is not in the dom which means if script reach the element before loading it, there is a problem for stale element especially in chrome driver. better idea to add some waiting code. thanks @alecxe

Comment: I think alecxe is right because I got this error: Failure/Error: elements[i].click()
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError:
       Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Comment: I did, but I failed to mentioned that inside each li there is an a tag. so I modifed the code to this: `elements = @driver.find_elements(css: ".account-item>a")`

Comment: `for i in 0..elements.size

  elements[i].click()

  # wait until the element loads
    wait.until { @driver.find_element(css: ".account-list > li:nth-child(#{i})>a")}`

Comment: @IsraelBautista it should wait before click

Comment: how would you select the next <a> tag?

Comment: @IsraelBautista as you did it `".account-list > li:nth-child(#{i}) > a"`